# GtkPositionType

Tags: application-development, quickly

The problem is that I have to use function attach_next_to() on grid, but the optional parameter of that function is GtkPositioType for side on which I can attach some new widget od the grid. What ever I try

```
Gtk.POS_LEFT
Gtk.GTK_POS_LEFT
```

or something else, I get error

```
'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'POS_LEFT
```

My question is how to get GtkPositionType in python, I can see in documetation that it is enum type, but if I wrote

```
self.grid.attach_next_to(1,1,1)
```

if I supose that first argument if for lef, I get error

```
that function expect 6 arguments. Pls. help, and sry for bad english
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is: get the enum type name and add a dot after Gtk.
So you get:
`Gtk.PositionType.LEFT`